# React Native & Firebase Cloud Storage - Create buckets dynamically

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, react-native-firebase

I am looking at creating an app that uses cloud storage for image storing, and according to [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control) it seems like it is smart to create a bucket per user. However, this seems like a bad idea when you think about scaleability and such because you'd have millions of buckets. My question is: for an app that uses storage buckets to store images, is it better to create a per-user bucket or use a single bucket and just name files uniquely according to user-email and limit accesses to the files inside to each user?

It seems like every doc I visit mentions creating the bucket either in the console or in gsutil but I am looking to see if there is a way to do it from the react-native client side. This way when a user creates a new account, a new bucket can be allocated to them. I have looked into the Google Cloud JSON API too.

Comment: It depends if your use case really needs to store users' data in separate bucket. Also are you using Firebase Storage (so you can use security rules) and Firebase Auth? Create Bucket APIs can be called from server only so you might need Cloud Functions/server.

Comment: All those buckets are meant for is hold strictly pictures, and whether or not those pictures contain sensitive information is up to the users. Ideally security rules can make it easy so that files belonging to 1 user doesn't get accessed by others, but that's why I thought individual buckets will reduce wrong accessss. I am using Firebase Storage and Auth, and I am not using Cloud Functions / server.